# Methods of Making Your TurtleBot3 Speak

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone gotten a TurtleBot3 listening for speech and then responding? If so, what libraries have you used?

Note: I'm currently using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273887/methods-of-making-your-turtlebot3-speak/) by [jonasro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31848/jonasro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a existing setup for the Turtlebot3, but if none turns up, for the recognition part see [this previous answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/246247/speech-recognition-packages-for-ros-kinetic-kame/). For the "speak" part it's probably easiest to use/adapt the method described here: [sound_play](http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play?distro=kinetic).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonasro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31848/jonasro/) on 2017-10-24**:
Thanks Stefan. I've tried using pocketsphinx which ended up working well, but at the cost of some poor recognition of my dictionary. Have you used sound_play? If so, what would be the advantages of using that over pyttsx?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-10-25**:
Didn't use it, but pyttsx looks like it's just fine for what you're doing. I guess a slight advantage of sound_play would be that you can publish what to say on a topic, but that's easy to reproduce with pyttsx too.